# Laravel Eloquent Condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question about Laravel Eloquent

There are 2 models

```
class User extends Model
{
    public static function search() {
        $request = request();
        return User::where(function ($q) use ($request) {
            $member_level = $request->get('member_level');
            $member_phone = $request->get('member_phone');
            $member_name = $request->get('member_name');
            $member_id = $request->get('member_id');

            if ($member_level) {
                $q->where('member_level', $member_level);
            }
            if ($member_phone) {
                $q->where('member_phone', $member_phone);
            }
            if ($member_name) {
                $q->where('member_name', $member_name);
            }
            if ($member_id) {
                $q->where('member_id', $member_id);
            }
    });
}
```

```
class Deposit extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }    
}
```

The user has a Deposit class.

In another controller I used search function as follow

```
User::search()->get()
```

My question is that I want to use the search() in the User model in the controller with the Deposit model.

```
Deposit::whereHas('user',function($q) {
    condition from User::search().
})
```

is there any way to do this? 
As  I am developing an admin page, there are a lot of search pages that are repeating for every page. Could you please share your idea if there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
class Deposit extends Model
{
    public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Member::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

   public function searchUser(){
         return $this->user()->search();
    }   
}
```

And use it

```
Deposit::whereHas('searchUser')
```